# Sharefile folder shows different files as one

Tags: api, delphi, intraweb, sharefile

There are 3 files uploaded to Sharefile using Sharefile API. 2 of which are PDF's and named slightly different. Since 11/2/2020 both the pdf's are showing up uploaded as one (the names are concatenated with a comma) they used to be uploaded as 2 different files as their filenames are appended with _App or _Qte at the end. Example: Jane_Doe_100-1_HO_10-20-2020_App-8625.pdf,Jane_Doe_100-1_HO_10-20-2020_Qte-8625_4112020082002.pdf

Is anybody else have this problem. Sharefile support has been contacted and they said they do not support API calls.

We haven't made any changes to the code.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Since you know the date the problem started, lookup in your version control what changes you (or somebody) made then, despite that you say that no changes are made. Also, I hope you do understand that it is impossible to say what goes wrong without the code that makes the filenames and uploads the files. So please edit your question and supply that code.

Comment: Tom,Thank you for responding. The version control system did not show any changes. What I had to do was split the upload proc into 2 and upload each file seperately. Although Sharefile API allows\uses Multipar tForm DataStream to enable sending files of the same type/extension as part of one stream i seems they no longer upload the files seperately.

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was split the upload proc into 2 and upload each file separately. Although Sharefile API allows\uses Multipart Form DataStream to enable sending files of the same type/extension as part of one stream, it seems they no longer upload the files separately. So I had to upload both the pdf files seperately.